# ViewPager with Picasso not loading inside RecyclerView Row

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a viewPager in my recyclerview for any posts with images, the images are being retrieved and loaded into picasso fine but my recycler view is not displaying it. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my RecyclerView adapter calling the ViewPager adapter

```
      if (posts.getPost().getImages() != null) {

            ImagePagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(mContext, posts.getPost().getImages());
            holder.imageViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        }
```

and then here's my imagePagerAdapter

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<PostImageBundle> postImages = new ArrayList<>();

public ImagePagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PostImageBundle> postImageBundles) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.postImages = postImageBundles;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return postImages.size();
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return (view == (LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_image_item, null);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagePost);
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(postImages.get(position).getMedium().getUrl())
            .into(imageView);

    container.addView(view);

    return view;
}
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to set a fixed height for my ViewPager.... that was the problem